# drush inheritance, site-ssh and site-list

Tags: drush, ssh

It's possible I'm going about this all wrong, and I should be setting up my aliases file differently.

We have a set up with 4 load-balanced production servers running the same code and accessing the same database. I want to set up a drush aliases file to access them by a short name and also allow commands to be run on all of them simultaneously. Here's what I have so far, in `~/.drush/cust.aliases.drushrc.php`:

```
<?php
$aliases['production'] = array (
  'root' => '/var/www/cust',
  'uri' => 'www.example.com',
  'databases' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'database' => '...',
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'host' => '...',
        'port' => '3306',
        'driver' => 'mysql',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'site-list' => array(
    'production.1',
    'production.2',
    'production.3',
    'production.4',
  ),
);
$aliases['production.1'] = array (
  'parent' => '@production',
  'remote-host' => '...',
  'site-list' => array(),
);
$aliases['production.2'] = array (
  'parent' => '@production',
  'remote-host' => '...',
);
$aliases['production.3'] = array (
  'parent' => '@production',
  'remote-host' => '...',
);
$aliases['production.4'] = array (
  'parent' => '@production',
  'remote-host' => '...',
);
?>
```

Now the problem I have is that the `site-list` variable is being added to the individual definitions, so the `site-ssh` command thinks that they are a list. I've tried a few things to sort this out, including adding `'site-list' => NULL`, `'site-list' => array()` and `'site-list' => ''` to the the `production.x` definitions, but this doesn't work since [`site-ssh` just uses `isset`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/21b7845294ef18f5e4b4382e904d8883d2feb111/commands/core/ssh.drush.inc#L57). Neither do my attempts to use the `unset` function because the inheritance happens after I've tried to unset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Drush will always prefer the non-empty 'site-list' in @production over any empty value you provide in the specific site aliases.  This is regrettable, as it makes it Hard to delete values.

There are a couple of alternatives, though.  The most straightforward solution is to just take advantage of the fact that Drush alias files are executable php.  You can refactor your alias definitions like this:

```
<?php
$common = array (
  'root' => '/var/www/cust',
  'uri' => 'www.example.com',
  'databases' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'database' => '...',
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'host' => '...',
        'port' => '3306',
        'driver' => 'mysql',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$aliases['production'] = array (
  'site-list' => array(
    'production.1',
    'production.2',
    'production.3',
    'production.4',
  ),
);
$aliases['production.1'] = array (
  'remote-host' => '...',
) + $common;
$aliases['production.2'] = array (
  'remote-host' => '...',
) + $common;
$aliases['production.3'] = array (
  'remote-host' => '...',
) + $common;
$aliases['production.4'] = array (
  'remote-host' => '...',
) + $common;
```

Your second option is to take advantage of a Drush feature that automatically creates group aliases for all aliases that are defined in a single alias file.  Start with your alias file definition as you show it in the question above; then:

1) Delete 'site-list' from the 'production' alias.

2) Move the 'production' alias to a different file (I use servers.aliases.drushrc.php to store aliases to all of the servers that I have sites on).

3) Keep the individual site aliases as they are, with `'parent' => '@server.production'`.

Once you have done that, you may use `@cust` as an alias list for all of the aliases defined in cust.aliases.drushrc.php.

Comment: I tried the first solution to this (using a separate `$common` array), which mostly works, except for that `drush @cust.production status` fails with
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach() backend.inc:707              [warning]`. I don't really want to go down the route of more files, as I'd like to be able to distribute a single file around the team. Is this a bug in my distro's drush 5.10.0 version?

Comment: Drush 5 isn't supported any longer. If you find you're having the same problem with Drush 7, post a bug to the Drush project on GitHub. We can fix it, and backport it to Drush 6.

Comment: OK, so after a `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`, I tried `drush @cust.production status` again, and it still failed. This time I got a more helpful error message though: `Not found: production.1, production.2, production.3, production.4    [warning]`. If I change the content of the `site-list` to be `@cust.production.x` then it works. Is this a bug that I should report or expected behaviour?