# Execute drush command against against multiple groups

Tags: drush

We have a large set of Drupal instances, and we use Drush alias groups to group them logically. For example, we have a group "dev" for all sites "in development", and, for example, another called "7_36" for all on Drupal core 7.36.

I can currently run commands against all sites in a single group (`drush @dev status`), but is it possible to run a command against all sites which are in both groups? For example, I'd like to run a command against all sites found both in @dev and in @7_36.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new alias group that is the combination of the two (by hand):

```
$aliases['newCombinedGroup'] = array(
  'site-list' => array(
    // Dev group 1 sites
    'site1', 
    'site2',
    'site3',
    // 7_36 group 2 sites
    'site6', 
    'site7',
    'site8',
  ),
);
```

This is discussed in this other thread:
[How to use Drush's concurrent execution capability?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60565/how-to-use-drushs-concurrent-execution-capability)

Another option as pointed out by the maintainer of Drush here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/134472/3279

is to *compose* your alias group site names for example from a PHP array of site names, then build your alias entries programmatically by looping through these site  names and filling out the contents of the drush alias itself.

So something like:

```
// This is untested example code.
$sites_in_dev = array('site-dev-1', 'site-dev-2');
$sites_in_736 = array('site-1', 'site-2');

$aliases['newCombinedGroup'] = array(
  'site-list' => $sites_in_dev + $sites_in_736;
);
$aliases['@dev'] = array('site-list' => $sites_in_dev);
$aliases['@7_36'] = array('site-list' => $sites_in_736);

foreach ($sites_in_dev as $sitename) {
  if ($sitename == 'site-dev-1') {
    $aliases['Dev1'] = array( /* ... */ );
  }
  if ($sitename == 'site-dev-1') {
    $aliases['Dev2'] = array( /* ... */ );
  }
}

foreach ($sites_in_736 as $site) {
  // ... etc ...
}
```

.... You get the idea. Also I would refrain from using `@7_36` as an alias name. In general PHP variables shouldn't start with numbers -- and while an alias isn't a php variable persay you're playing with fire by giving it a name that would be an invalid php variable name; when evaluated now and in future versions of Drush ... who knows how that will behave.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This was helpful to me, as a newbie in drupal. However, seems that as of my current drush version (8.1.10), your first example should have been written as follows: `$aliases['newCombinedGroup'] = array(
  'site-list' => array(
    // Dev group 1 sites
    '@site1', 
    '@site2',
    '@site3',
    // 7_36 group 2 sites
    '@site6', 
    '@site7',
    '@site8',
  ),
);`

Comment: @icasimpan yes, mostly likely your recommendation is correct. My post was from 2015, and Drush receives regular updates and so it's conventions change slightly over time.